# Django dynamic form with text and **images** through AJAX

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax, django-forms

I'm trying to create a website for creating articles, and by an article, I mean legit article with arbitrary number of text fields and images. (No just a plain single `models.TextField` stuff... which is mostly taught to get started with django).

I have some priorities for key features to work for as well.

1. User can add as many text field, and image field as possible.
2. As soon as user uploads the image, it gets showed up as a preview.

Now recently I learned AJAX, so I've done 90% of the work already, by putting the dynamic content into a JSON format, containing full info about the article as {"title": "...", "heading": "...", "text": "...", "heading": "...", "text": "..."}, and I'm storing that as the article content by using the `request.GET` in the view, and later I'd loop through that to display all the sub contents of the article in that same order. 
So here I'm AJAX -

```js
const ArticleContent = JSON.stringify(ArticleObject);

jQuery.ajax({
    url: "{% url 'upload-article' %}",
    data: {
    title: ArticleTitle,
    description: ArticleDescription,
    content: ArticleContent
    }
})
```

And then by using that to create and save the new article

```py
title = request.GET.get('title', None)
description = request.GET.get('description', None)
content = request.GET.get('content', None)

article = Article.objects.create(
    title = title,
    description = description,
    content = content,
    author = request.user
)
```

The problem is **sending the images**, I just couldn't get that part.
How can I send the list (array) of all the images I've upload in the article template through ajax to the django so that I can do something like...

```py
title = request.GET.get('title', None)
description = request.GET.get('description', None)
content = request.GET.get('content', None)
images = request.GET.get('images', None)
...
...
for image in images:
    Image.objects.create(image = image, article = article)
```

I've also discovered django formsets, which allows to have arbitrary number of forms (in my case an image form), but the problem with this approach is - it is against the usage of AJAX, and it make the page refreshes anytime a new image is uploaded...

So now I'm basically a lot confused like what's the best approach to doing something like this.
All suggestions are appreciated. And I'm also open to whole new approach as well (like using php etc...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you need to create Image model which has a post id field as a foreign key.

```
def get_image_filename(instance, filename):
    id = instance.article.id
    return "article_images/%s" % (id)  


class Images(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, default=None)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_filename,
                              verbose_name='Image')
```

And in forms.py, you can create Article Forma and ImageForm class for uploading images for the article.

```
class ArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=128)
    content = forms.CharField(max_length=245, label="Item Description.")

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('title', 'body', )

class ImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    image = forms.ImageField(label='Image')    
    class Meta:
        model = Images
        fields = ('image', )
```

Finally in views.py, you can create post function that deals with post request for images data.(this is just an example)

```
def post(request):
    ImageFormSet = modelformset_factory(Images,
                                        form=ImageForm, extra=3)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ArticleForm(request.POST)
        formset = ImageFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES,
                               queryset=Images.objects.none())
        if form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.user = request.user
            post.save()
            for form in formset.cleaned_data:
                image = form['image']
                photo = Images(post=post, image=image)
                photo.save()
            messages.success(request,
                             "Posted!")
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
        else:
            print form.errors, formset.errors
    else:
        form = ArticleForm()
        formset = ImageFormSet(queryset=Images.objects.none())
    return render(request, 'index.html',
                  {'articleForm': form, 'formset': formset},
                  context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```